# Sort downloads by creation date

Tags: bash, find

I want to sort my downloads by year and month into my archive. I can do it by hand with:

```
P="~/archive"
find ~/downloads -maxdepth 1 -not -iname "." -printf "mv -i \"~/downloads/%f\" $P/%CY-%Cm/\n"
```

but I wanted to be able to add it to cron, so I tried:

```
P="~/archive"
find ~/downloads -maxdepth 1 -not -iname "." -printf "\"~/downloads/%f\" $P/%CY-%Cm/\n"|while read f;do mv -i $f; done
```

Not sure if I'm over engineering the problem or just missing one exec.

Comment: The `~` does not expand under quotes for a start! should have been just `P=~/archive` or `P="$HOME/archive"`, but remember that the `HOME` path varies when run under `cron`

Comment: And if you are putting this directly in your `crontab` you cannot use Bashisms like `~` (though *running* a Bash script from `cron` is of course fine) and you need to double any `%` signs.

Comment: @lnian `HOME` doesn't "vary" at all; it will always refer to the home directory of the user whose cron job is being run.